# jboss-as maven plugin: undeploy by reg-ex does not work

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x

My ear files have version in them. For example, myApp-1.0.1.ear or myApp-1.0.2.ear. I'm trying to undeploy by regex(cause I don't know what the current version is), and then deploy.

However, undeploy by regex is not working for me. I'm looking for 'myApp-*.ear', however it doesn't work unless the version in pom matches the version of current deployment...

what am I doing wrong?

Here's my pom.xml

```
...
<version>1.0.0</version>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.Final</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>clean</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>undeploy</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <match-pattern>myApp-*.ear</match-pattern>
              <ignoreMissingDeployment>true</ignoreMissingDeployment>
              <matchPatternStrategy>fail</matchPatternStrategy>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>install-application</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
...
```

Comment: I think you need `myApp-.*\.ear`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem too.

Comment: I've filed a bug for the maintainers here https://issues.jboss.org/projects/WFMP/issues/WFMP-45?filter=allopenissues

Comment: Have you considered deploying the application with the --force option under a deployment name that would not contain the version so that a newer version replaces the old one?

Comment: I figured out my problem. The argument should be real regex not just basic wildcard. That's the confusion you get when spending too much time on the terminal. Using `prefix.*` as opposed to just `prefix*` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Following the source code of the undeploy plugin will bring you [here](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/plugin/common/DeploymentInspector.java). That use [`String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method. So what you need is something like:

```
      <configuration>
          <match-pattern>myApp.+\.ear</match-pattern>
          <ignoreMissingDeployment>true</ignoreMissingDeployment>
          <matchPatternStrategy>fail</matchPatternStrategy>
      </configuration>
```

Where `myApp` literal is followed by `.+` (any char one or more times), `\.` (dot literal) and  `ear` literal
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912894/how-to-match-any-character-in-java-regular-expression) have some good information about java regex.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to upgrade the plugin version as i just ran through latest jboss docs and found below configuration which is slightly different then yours.

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.Final</version>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <phase>clean</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>undeploy-artifact</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xxxxx</artifactId>
                  <version>x.x.x</version>
                  <type>ear</type>
                  <name>xxxxx.ear</name>
                  <match-pattern>myApp-.*</match-pattern>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```