# regex masking patterns

Tags: regex

I have these inputs:

```
DFDBDFDFDF21R123
DFDBDFDFDF34R123
```

I want to match these inputs, except positions 9 and 10, like below:

```
DFDBDFDFxxR123
DFDBDFDFxxR123
```

So, to be clear: match 1-8, exclude 9-10, match 11-16.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match "any character" in Java Regular Expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912894/how-to-match-any-character-in-java-regular-expression)

Comment: Why not `(.{8})..(.+) `?

Comment: Or, `string_new = string_old.replace("(.{8})..(.+)", "$1$2");`

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln of

> > (.{8})..(.+)

The 'thing' you are missing from your understanding of Regex is 'grouping'

```
(SOME MATCHING SUB-STRING A)(SOME MATCHING SUB-STRING B)
```

If you use regex like this, you can do lots of nice things including 'pull out' parts of a line and then re-arrange them. But it also helps you group 'parts' that you want to search for.

so his

```
.{8}
```

matches '.' which is 'any single character' and then {8} means 'match any single character 8 times.

```
 (.{8})
```

means 'group the first 8 characters' for use.

```
..
```

means 'match any two characters'

```
 .+
```

means 'match 1 or more of 'any character'

```
 (.+)
```

means "group that 1 or more of 'any character' for later use"

Therefore...

When you put them all together you get

```
 (.{8})..(.+)
```

Which means 'match the first 8 characters (any 8 characters) as group 1' then 'any two characters' then '1 or more characters as group 2'

This would allow you to (depending on your regex client/etc.) is use $1 and $2 to print out, use or ...whatever... the values of group 1 and/or group 2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see what grouping has to do with the user's question. He's looking to match some string while ignoring some characters. This can be achieved with `.`. There is no need to involve any other regex feature.

Comment: ahh, he edited the question and made it more clear that he wanted 'exact' string matches, not 'whatever string matches this pattern' Then yes, this is a little bit much, and not actually 'exactly' what he needs, but still use of groups when does smart (even if you don't use them later) can help with regex clarity.