# Unable to fetch numbers from string by java split() method

Tags: java, array-algorithms

I have this code which takes an IP address(string) of the format 255.255.255.255 
and needs to perform some post processing on those numbers (not posted here) but for which the string must be converted into an array of ints.

I have used here the `split()` method  but it's not giving me the result.
I saw other answers on sp doing it with regex but none of them worked for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String text;

        Scanner take=new Scanner(System.in);
        text=take.nextLine();
        String data[]=text.split(".",4);

        for(String w:data){
            System.out.println(w);
        }
        take.close();
    }
}
```

I have tried with the input  12.36.26.25

But it outputs 36.26.25 which was supposed to be like 
12
36
26
25

Comment: i love the "please dont mark as duplicate" haha. gimme a sec to look over the code

Comment: Try escaping the period (`\\.`) as it's a special regex symbol (it matches any character).

Comment: can u just tell me where to put the modification?

Comment: `.` is regex match.  Use escape characters.

Comment: if you want a challange, write your own "split" method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use it like that:

```
        String example="12.36.26.25";
        String data[]=example.split("\\.");

        for(String w:data){
            System.out.println(w);
        }
```

And it will do what you want ;)

Using split(regex,limit) as you did will actually split on any character (since . is the regex for any character) and it will basically remove the first few characters

Comment: as simple as that lmao

Comment: what is the significance of " \\." can u please explain?

Comment: let me refer to this post aswell

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674930/java-regex-meta-character-and-ordinary-dot
in conjunction to Veselin Davidov's answer

Comment: It escapes the '.' character. Basically '.' is the regex form of any character

Comment: If you're not familiar with regular expressions, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912894/how-to-match-any-character-in-regular-expression .. or just do some googling ;)

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `java.util.regex` package:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Main{

     public static void main(String args[]){
        String text = "12.36.26.25";
        String separator = ".";
        String[] data = text.split(Pattern.quote(separator));
        System.out.println(data.length);
        for(String w: data){
            System.out.println(w);
        }
    }
}
```

The Pattern.quote will do the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you guys an alternative solution aswell:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String text;

        Scanner take=new Scanner(System.in);
        text=take.nextLine();
        String data[]=text.split("[.]");

        for(String w:data){
            System.out.println(w);
        } 
        take.close();
    }
```

you can escape the dot using "[.]" as a string, turning the dot from an regex operator into a literal char

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line

```
String data[]=text.split(".",4);
```

to

```
String data[]=text.split("\\.");
```

Comment: For all the special character the escape \\ is required. They are  \, ^, $, ., |, ?, *, +, (, ), [, ], {, }

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to use the `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil` to extract the numbers from a given String of an IPAddress as below-

```
String ipAddressString = "10.20.30.40";
byte[] numbers = IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(ipAddressString);
```

The numbers in ByteArray format can be converted to integer array using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438071/6761121).