# I don't understand why matcher.find() always return false

Tags: java, regex

My String page contain this page http://www.posh24.se/kandisar and I want to extract everything between

```
<div class="channelListEntry">
```

and

```
</div>
```

and put the result into an `ArrayList`.

The things is the `matcher.find()` always returns `false`.

```
private ArrayList<String> extracted = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void extractChannel(String htmlPage){

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"channelListEntry\">(.*?)</div>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlPage);

    while(matcher.find()){ // Always return false
        System.out.println("hello ?");
        extracted.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

I expect to copy the text between tags in my array.

Comment: Use an XML parser instead of regex matching. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Pattern.DOTALL flag when compiling the pattern so it matches multilines - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2913756/9335036

Comment: Also, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DTeDtz/1) is an awesome resource to help build more complex regexes.

Comment: Thank you, the Pattern.DOTALL do the thing and it works but when i try to escape the dash charater, android studio say "Illegal escape character in string literal".

Comment: No i mean i cant compile if i try to escape the dash character.

Comment: Yeah, my question was does it compile if you don't escape it.

Comment: if i dont escape it i can compile !

Comment: Oh, cool. I edited the answer since that step is not needed. Glad it works.