# Does anybody know what is the reason that question mark matches nothing in ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: bash, grep

When i use a dot(.) in globbing pattern, it successfully matches this bunch of addresses:

```
~$ ip addr show | grep i.et
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
inet 192.168.1.101/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
inet6 fe80::c705:4836:6aa7:d321/64 scope link noprefixroutet
```

At the same time, the question-marked version matches nothing:

```
~$ ip addr show | grep i?et
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're confusing regular expressions and filename wildcards.

Comment: `?` matches any character in wildcards, `.` matches any character in regular expressions. `grep` only does regular expressions.

Comment: Escape it: `\?`

Comment: and always quote regular expressions given on the command line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match "any character" in regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912894/how-to-match-any-character-in-regular-expression)

Comment: Note, too, that `i?et`, as a filename pattern, could match one or more files in the current directory, resulting in those names being passed as arguments, not the literal string `i?et`.

Comment: As unmatched patterns are treated literally by default in `bash`, `grep` will *probably* get the regular expression `i?et` as its argument, which matches an optional `i` followed by `et`.

Answer (score 1):

Grep's patterns are [regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Fundamental-Structure.html#Fundamental-Structure). The question mark you are trying to use is part of [Bash's globbing (pattern matching)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching).

Example using globbing:

```
ls -1d /proc/191?
```

returns :

```
/proc/1910
/proc/1913
/proc/1914
/proc/1915
/proc/1916
/proc/1918
/proc/1919
```

Now with grep's regular expressions (regex):

```
ls -1 /proc | grep '191.'
```

returns:

```
1910
1913
1914
1915
1916
1918
1919
```

Hope that helps clear up the confusion.