# How can I define a "anything" mask with imask.js?

Tags: javascript, imaskjs

Consider the following minimal example. I'm using [imask.js](https://imask.js.org/) to restrict input field values. But sometimes I just don't care about the value and would like to allow anything.

If I don't set a value for the [`mask`](https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-base) property it throws an error because it is required in the configuration:

> Uncaught Error: mask property should be defined at maskedClass

So I figured out a workaround with a custom block `mask: {}`. But it still shows warnings and doesn't look like a solid solution to me.

What is the correct way to define a mask that allows any value?

```js
IMask(document.getElementById("input"), {
  mask: "Digit here: 0. Anything here: anything",
  lazy: false,
  blocks: {
    anything: {
      mask: {}
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input { width: 50vw; padding: 10px; font-size: large; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<input id="input"/>
```

Comment: Cool library. I need this. ... How about using a regex (in/as your mask) that matches any character, see here for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912894/how-to-match-any-character-in-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@GetSet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1780873/getset), you could use a RegExp mask that matches anything :

```js
IMask(document.getElementById("input"), {
  mask: "Digit here: 0. Anything here: anything",
  lazy: false,
  blocks: {
    anything: {
      mask: /(.*?)/
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input { width: 50vw; padding: 10px; font-size: large; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<input id="input"/>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711971/regular-expressions-match-anything) if you want more examples of RegExp that matches anything.